# Session objects not being retrieved in a different web app in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-variables, session-state

I have two Websites ReportsSite and CustomerPortal. I login to the CustomerPortal, post successful login I create two Session objects Session[UserDetails] and Session[Uri].
The customer portal has a link which opens the homepage of the ReportsSite. The session objects created in the customerportal cannot be accessed in ReportSite despite the sites being run on the same system from visual studio. If go back to the CustomerPortal by clicking the back button the session objects are available. The sessionstate mode is InProc

Comment: Is passing the session variable through the link query string an option?

Comment: If your session state is InProc then each web app will maintain their own session state.  You will need to move to a shared session state provider like sql server or redis etc

Comment: @Baral yes.. I am using SSO..

Comment: @bhmahler but wouldn't using SqlSever state be heavy?

Comment: @MuayyadDiab Nope.. My session object contains authorization data.

Comment: Not necessarily, the session state provider for sql server is pretty light.  If you need it shared between processes than you have to use something both processes can access

Comment: @bhmahler Ok. Will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to move to using a shared sessions state provider so that both applications have access to the session store.

SQL Server is an option
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317604/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-store-asp-net-session-state

More about session state
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

> **SQLServer** mode stores session state in a SQL Server database. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.